# How to inline function map on Flux or Mono object in Kotlin and Project Reactor

Tags: kotlin, project-reactor

I'm trying to develop a demo app using Kotlin and Project Reactor and I want to inline some functions like `map` on objects like `Flux` or `Mono`.

I did like this:

```
private inline fun Flux<Account>.map(noinline transformer: (Account) -> AccountDTO): Flux<AccountDTO> {
    return this.map(transformer)
}
```

but it's not ok because I'm receiving the following warning from IDEA:

```
Expected performance impact of inlining 'private open inline fun Flux<Account>.map(noinline transformer: (Account) -> AccountDTO): Flux<AccountDTO> defined in com.freesoft.reactiveaccountservice.api.controller.AccountController' is insignificant. Inlining works best for functions with parameters of functional types.
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can implement this inline functions or if it matters to implement it?

Tx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far as you are just calling the non-inlined `map` defined in Java, there won't be a benefit. You could in principle look at the Java definition, and translate it to Kotlin, and make that your inlined `map`'s defintion, but (without checking) I'd expect it just to be something like `return new MapFlux(...)` which probably won't benefit either because the lambda needs to be stored in a field.

So you'd need to reimplement a considerable portion of the library in Kotlin.

Comment: Ok. I've read more about this and I think that now I'm understanding somehow which functions should be inlined and map in this case is not worthing. If I have a map on a collection instead of a Mono/Flux object, then map will be worth to be inlined, right?

Comment: "Worth inlining" depends mostly on the definition of function, not on the description of what it does. But generally speaking, yes (if you don't count e.g. Java streams as collections).

Answer (score 2):

Usually, you want to inline **lambda** functions which are passed into **higher-order** functions because it reduces the runtime overhead. No anonymous classes and function reference objects will be created during runtime when you inline the lambdas. In your case, inlining doesn't boost performance because it's a regular function. You can read full explanation with examples [here](https://medium.com/tompee/idiomatic-kotlin-inline-functions-e39b2f90a291)